# How to solve 'window is not defined' Error in Node JS on Terminal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to include angular JS Using require so I am using below code

```
var ang = require('angular');
```

But It displays error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I Know window object not defined in node console but help me how to avoid this error ?

I hope my question understandable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `window` object is only defined in the browser, and isn't defined within Node.js (which uses `process` instead).

The reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to require a module (angular.js) that was intended to be used with the DOM from a browser, and not within the Node.js environment.

If you want to include angular in your HTML code, include it like you would any other JS file using a  tag.