# node app.js results in "window not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, socket.io

From research in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250121/how-to-solve-window-is-not-defined-error-in-node-js-on-terminal), I understand that this has to do with `window` being defined in the browser and not in `node`. However, I'm not entirely clear on how to remedy the situation. My goal is to just start my server so I can preview a website I built (and make sure it looks good).

Here's my app.js file:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('answers', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('gum', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
});

angular.module('NoteWrangler', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

Here's the error I get when entering node app.js into Terminal:

```
/Users/Kristin/node_modules/angular/angular.js:26057
})(window, document);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous 
(/Users/Kristin/node_modules/angular/angular.js:26057:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kristin/node_modules/angular/index.js:1:63)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to achieve? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Apologies. Edited to add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared an angular reference inside your **server**: `angular.module('NoteWrangler', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);`

Angular.JS is a **client** library it's not used on the **server side**.

You may want to use [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) if you're using Angular 2.

Comment: Apologies. I'm new at this. Are you saying that would instead need to go inside my index.html file?

Comment: Yes, it's 2 separate things.

Comment: Try to find a guide "express/angular" and use a generator like this one:https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-angular

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Tried removing reference to Angular, but the window error is still there, unfortunately. :- /

Comment: Can you send us the error? If you have removed the reference it's a new one

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to run a static server, try using [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server?ts=2), a command line tool.

As other users have mentioned, the `window` bug is happening because Angular is not intended to be used server side. To remedy the problem, just remove the line of code that mentions `angular`.

Comment: I tried this and got this error: Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib

Should I use cd to get it to look in the correct folder?

Comment: try to use sudo?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using XAMPP or WampServer ? These two guys occupy port 80 by default on a localhost. That is, http://localhost:80.

Try changing the port from 80 to say 3000.

NB: Node js does not require WAMP or XAMPP, so if the any conflict at the ports level.

Then restart the node server.